# How to get a string into a where clause in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class method:

```
def self.default_column
  "created_at"
end
```

How can I rewrite the following function, so that I can make use of my `default_column` method?

```
def next
  User.where("created_at > ?", created_at).order('created_at ASC').first
end
```

I tried things like these...

```
def next
  User.where("#{default_column} > ?", default_column).order('#{default_column} ASC').first
end
```

... but I must be awfully wrong here because it doesn't work at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you move `next` to `def self.next` and call it like `User.next` I think it'll make sense (and work)

Comment: Ignoring the `where` call for a moment, the `order` call will not work because `#{...}` blocks in strings are only evaluated when the string is wrapped with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def next
  default_column = self.class.default_column
  User
  .where("#{default_column} > ?", send(default_column))
  .order("#{default_column} ASC")
  .first
end
```

Comment: Actually, this one turned out to work really well in my particular case. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
def next
  User.where("#{User.default_column} > ?", self.send(User.default_column)).order("#{User.default_column} ASC").first
end
```

Or even better

```
def next
  klass = self.class # This is supposing you are inside User model
  # Otherwise just use klass = User
  klass.where("#{klass.default_column} > ?", self.send(klass.default_column))
       .order(klass.arel_table[klass.default_column].asc)
end
```

Notice that if you handle the method in this way, you cannot chain it: like `User.where(name: 'something').next`

If you want to achieve this, you have to move `next` to be `def self.next` and in that case, you have to pass an instance of the user to it, like this:

```
def self.next(user)
  klass = user.class
  klass.where("#{klass.default_column} > ?", user.send(klass.default_column))
       .order(klass.arel_table[klass.default_column].asc)
end
```

In this way you can write something like: `User.where(name: 'test').next(@user)`. You can optionally chain `.first` to get directly the result, but in this way you will not be able to chain other things, like `User.where(name: 'test').next(@user).where(email: 'my@mail.com')`

Finally, if you want **pure AREL** (for portability)

```
def self.next(user)
  klass        = user.class
  arel         = klass.arel_table
  column       = klass.default_column # This helps cleaning up code
  column_value = user.send(column)

  klass.where(arel[column].gt(column_value))
       .order(arel[column].asc)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this write-up. I found this really helpful and ended up using a mixture of your code and sawa's.